# Why is the button doing nothing? (Login system

Tags: javascript, html

This code is doing nothing when I click the login button with the right login details, I took the suggestions from the comments to have this code, do I need to add args into the onClickHandler function? but which ones?

```
    <input id="login" style="display: block" type="button" value="Log In" name="Submit" onclick="onClickHandler()" >
    <script>
    document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", onClickHandler());
    function onClickHandler() {
      validate(document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value,"Isaac",document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value,"Tewst")
    }
            </script>
```

Comment: Because you missed a `}` or `)` someplace.

Comment: in the function or the button? beacuse im not sure

Comment: Well, since your button violates every know best practice written since 1943, it probably is in the button.

Comment: hmmm I don't seem to find a missing `}` or `)` (and why did u -1 my thing :( please don't i need to post questions

Comment: Downvote wasn't from me, but it is because you did not show your debugging work.  You have to say what you think is the problem, and what things you tried to find as both the cause of the problem, and also the potential solution.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Your question is very clear, but the "I have no clue..." bit makes some believe you've not researched anything.

Comment: It is a better practice if you move all the code you have in the `"onclick"` attribute inside a function, suppose we call it `onClickHandler` , then use `document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", onClickHandler)`.

Comment: also wdym by "your button violates every know best practice written since 1943"

Comment: Read Rich's answer below - the last few lines explain.

Comment: @Shidersz i do not know how to do the event, like i did `function onClickHandler` but what do i put inside?

Comment: You need to put the code that call the function `validate()` with the arguments that it is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a double quoted string inside another double quoted string unless you escape the inner double quotes:

IE:

```
var str = "this shouldn"t be done";
var str = "the first str var isn\"t incorrect, this one is";
```

Or you can swap out the inner double quotes with single quotes instead:

IE:

```
var str = "this isn't a bad approach";
```

Really though, that is a ton of inline javascript.  You should break that out into an event listener or something.  Also, once you fix the escaping problem, you have other issues in this code, such as there not being an instance of any DOM element with an ID of "incorrect"

Comment: I want to change it to a function that handles it but I just don't rly have a clue where to start with

Comment: To change into a function, create a function like `myFunction()` and place it inside the onclick tag like `onclick="myFunction()"`, and then create a separate <script></script> tag and define the myFunction() function there.  Does that make sense now?

Comment: Also instead of iterating for 5 separate tests, create a for loop

Comment: @N8888 yes i knew that but idk how im gonna do the function like the inside parts like which code?

Comment: @DungeonMan First add a for loop to your validate function

Comment: @N8888 a loop for what in the validate function tho? i don't really see some repeating parts, is it the `embed.style.display = "block"` things?

Comment: in your `onclick` tag you have `javascript:validate(document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value,"test",document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value,"test"); validate(document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value,"test1",document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value,"test1"); validate(document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value,"test2",document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value,"test2"); validate(document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value,"test3",document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value,"test3"); ...` the document.getElementsByName is repeated, you could do a for loop on test[i]

Comment: There are like 5 validate function instances...which could have been put inside a for loop

Comment: got it, but I wanna know how to do the` function onClickHandler` thingy

Comment: I told you already, `onclick="myFunction()"` and then define the `myFunction()` in a separate script tag.  Rich's second answer explains that too..

Comment: also, that is not your original question, if you want to know how to do the 'inside code' inside the function, do it as a separate question.  This question is about the error message

Comment: Well I provided you an answer that will compensate for that ;) Hopefully it will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

To add an onclick listener, you can do it a couple ways:

Through straight jquery:

```
$('#id').on('click', function() { /* function code */ });
```

Or attach an onClick handle to your button:

```
<input id="login" style="display: block" type="button" value="Log In" onClick="DoEvent()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So in terms of your edited code, you need to make sure your `<input>` tag is inside a `<form>` tag, and also that the `onClickHandler` is a function with the `()`, in the `onclick` tag it isn't, nor is it placed inside the parenthesis.  Also, to not complicate life, I have provided a sample function `onClickHandler` that would validate your login credentials, that would consist of a username and a password input.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" Placeholder="enter username"><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" Placeholder="enter password"><br>
  <button id="login" style="display: block" type="button" value="Log In" name="Submit" onclick="onClickHandler()">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function onClickHandler() {
  var username = document.getElementById('username').value
 var pass = document.getElementById('password').value
  if (username == "admin" && pass == "Test") {
    window.open("whateverpage.html")
    alert('correct username')
  } else {
    alert('incorrect username or password')
  }
}
</script>
```

And if you insist on having the `validate` function inside the `onClickHandler` function (which I highly recommend not to do...it's really quite counter-intuitive), then you'd do it this way :

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="text1" Placeholder="something"><br>
  <input type="text" name="dasnk2" Placeholder="something else"><br>
  <button id="login" style="display: block" type="button" value="Log In" name="Submit" onclick="onClickHandler()">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function validate (first, second, third, fourth){/* put the validation code here */};

function onClickHandler() {
      arg1 = document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value;
      arg2 = "Isaac";
      arg3 = document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value;
      arg4 = "Tewst";
      validate(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have a function for validating already so like I don't rly know how to implement it. Should I send the whole code?

Comment: What is `document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value` and `document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value` referring to? You already have two inputs with names = "text1" and "dasnk2"?

Comment: I revised the answer to include the validate function

Answer (score 0):

and it should be downvoted because it is incomplete .. where is your validate function

the basic problem is your onClickHandler is executed, not assigned (onClickHandler not onClickHandler()) and it is executed before it is defined

organise your code

```
<html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="text1" value="bill" />
    <input type="text" name="dasnk2" />
    <input id="login" style="display: block" type="button" value="Log In" name="Submit" />
    <script>
    (function() {
        function validate( a,b,c,d) {
            console.log( a,b,c,d);
        }

        function onClickHandler() {
            validate(document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value,"Isaac",document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value,"Tewst")
        }
        document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", onClickHandler);
    })();
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```